# How do I get a certain set of posts from the database?

Tags: posts, database

We've just finished redesigning a blog that has almost daily posts.

Over the past month that we were redesigning it, there have been a large number of new posts that now need to be reincorporated into the database before we deploy the new site.

To get these new posts and upload them into the new site's database, what is the procedure? My guess is that we need to:

1. Export a sub-section of wp_posts and then import that into the new site.
2. Download recent content from wp-uploads and upload that into the same directory in the new site.

So when I'm exporting that most recent sub-section of wp-posts, what is the procedure to follow? And how do I coordinate that with the corresponding records in the wp_postmeta table?

Are there any other tables that need to be exported as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to your admin and go to "Tools -> Export" and you can customise what you want to export. Use the "Tools -> Import" on your other site.

If you have missing images, just copy them over from your `/uploads/` directory over to the new site

Comment: Great, this worked perfectly. I'm only wondering about some meta data that might have been lost, or is all of that included?

Comment: I've just done an export of one of my sites and can see a lot of meta information in there that matches up with the database. You can always do your export and search for any fields or data in the generated xml file to check for yourself. Good luck

Comment: @Alacritas - The "Tools > Export" does not contain some meta data the last modification date; as a result, the last modified date will show to be the creation date of the post.

Comment: @Will, thank you. Is there a way to obtain that data? It's not crucial with this particular site, but it could be important for future use cases.